# Android rank view

Tags: android

I would like to build a rank view. For example it can be a LinearLayout with vertical orientation. That layout would contain 4 other layouts or buttons and I would like to be able to change the order of those elements by long pressing on (for example second element) and moving that element at the top of the list).
Is there any ready-made solution for this problem maybe library. I have been trying to find but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [DragListView](https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView), which is frequently updated. Or is there a specific reason why you would like to use a `LinearLayout` instead of a ListView? ListViews can contain custom row layouts, so this would definitely work based on the requirements you've provided.